# ActiveRecord outside of Rails -- Connection is lost on HABTM?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to use ActiveRecord outside of Rails. I've got it mostly setup -- got my Rake tasks for the DB working, got my migrations working, and got some simple models working -- but I just tried to setup HABTM relationships and am getting problems.

It's very strange and I cannot seem to figure out how to fix it.

I called `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` to connect to MySQL. I've tried doing this once (before any models are loaded), once (after all models are loaded). I've tried this per-model by calling `establish_connection` in the models.

I can call basic methods.. `create`, `save`, etc. on my models.

I can call the HABTM associations and it *does return any associations that exist*.

Where this is messing up is if I try to *create* an association. For instance, running

```
p=Post.first # assume Post has HABTM relationship `tags`
p.tags # this works fine, and if I have some tags defined for `p` then this returns those associations

t=Tag.new(name: 'some tag')
p.tags << t # << DOES NOT WORK
p.tags.create(name: 'some tag') # << DOES NOT WORK
```

The error seems to indicate that a connection cannot be made to MySQL. It appears it is not using a password (*using password: NO*) -- however I *do* set a password in my call to `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening and/or how I might work around this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Do other relationships work? has_many and belongs_to for example?

Comment: ReggieB -- Great question. Don't think I got to the point of a `has_many` quite yet, but a belongs_to I know does work. I know that because at one point I tried both forms of HABTM (normal and `:through`), and while both of these associations don't work from one side, they *did* work on the intermediate `:through` model when I tried it that way. In other words, I could query directly on that table, call it posts_tags, and from there (since that model, PostsTag has a belongs_to), I can call "post" or "tag" on this model and that works fine. It's calling, say, `tags` on `Post` where this happens

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord/blob/master/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb as that seems to be a well used example of using ActiveRecord outside of rails. The line that stands out to me is ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = spec.stringify_keys and I wonder if ActiveRecord is a little fragile if you pass the configuration keys as symbols.